Why does "not" come after "it" in "he knows it not"?
I'm a layman in linguistics, and English is not my first language. I would like to know a little more about negation.
Following my curiosity, I was looking for an example of negation where "not" stands neither directly after the auxiliary verb, as it commonly does nowadays ("I do not know"), nor before a verb, as in negation of non-finite clauses (Cambridge Dictionary), nor even directly after the main verb, as it seems to do in the past ("I know not"), but directly after some other word.
I have found such an example in a 1791 book "The Philosophy of Ancient Greece Investigated", on page 248. The whole sentence:

If he knows that it is not in his thought, he must be sensible that he knows it not.

Here, the second "not" stands directly after "it". I don't remember seeing "not" in such a position anywhere, but I feel I could. Indeed, "that he knows not it" sounds unusual enough to my ear to be possible to be a clue for "not" in such a position being not that uncommon.
So, why does "not" stand here after "it"? Is it a separate construct, or maybe due to "not" being within the "that" clause? Or maybe it's just a matter of style, not grammar?
I would appreciate a broader linguistic explanation, and more examples of "not" in similar positions.
I'm not sure I'm clear enough. I couldn't come up with a better title. Please let me know if I can improve the question, or whether it is a duplicate.

Update. I wonder if putting "not" at the end of a clause, be it subordinate or not, or even the whole sentence?, could be a remain of the syntax of Old English. In the article about Jespersen's Cycle Wikipedia notes that

(…) "I didn't see" would be expressed in Old English as ic ne geseah; then strengthened with the word nauȝt (from Old English nawiht 'no thing') as Middle English I ne ysauȝ nauȝt; then leading to Early Modern English I saw not.

Maybe it is not that in the aforementioned "I saw not", "not" refers only to the verb, "saw". It might instead refer to the whole clause (?), which, as I interpret it, just happens here to contain only "saw".

Update. The more examples I see, the more I come to consider this syntax can be a way to avoid negating what should not be. Michael Seifert has quoted Macbeth in his comment to Colin Fine's answer; for me, "I have not thee" is likely to mean that an observer could reply "Whom then do you have?". In turn, "I have thee not" could be a reply to "Hast thou me?".
Probably style plays some role here, if we imagine the words being written, and intonation, if we imagine the words being spoken. Maybe I'm biased as I don't know Macbeth, and as I usually don't communicate with phrases so short. But indeed, I believe the length of the phrases may play a role; different word orders can have visibly different meanings.

Update. As far as I can understand Middle English, the 1391 treatise "A Treatise on the Astrolabe", by Geoffrey Chaucer, contains several occurrences of "not" used similarly to what I'm referring to in this question.
The version I'm going to quote is published by Wikisource; it is important because I've found another version, by Fordham University, which uses a different spelling of "not". I believe that Wikisource's "nat" is modern "not", as per Wiktionary.
First, Chaucer writes,

Forget nat this, litel Lowis.

where we can see "nat" directly after "forget", and before "this". There is a total of 3 occurrences of "nat this" in the whole treatise, but the other two seem to be too grammatically convoluted for me to analyze.
Then later Chaucer writes,

Tak keep of thise latitudes north and sowth, and forget it nat.

where we can see "nat" directly after "it", not "forget". There is a total of 3 occurrences of "it nat" in the whole treatise, all of them ending a sentence and being preceded directly by "forget".

Your English is excellent. However, "I don't remember to see" should be "I don't remember seeing". Your version is grammatically valid, but it doesn't quite mean what you intend.

Thanks for the correction! I've checked, and "remember to see" is indeed different from "remember seeing". The former sounds as if I don't want to forget to see "not", whatever that should mean. And glad to know in this post my English is good. I always appreciate feedback, good or bad, I'm still learning.

Re your update: I don't think so. I fear I misled you, when I spoke of "not" following the predicate. I've just had a look for "not" throughout Shakespeare, and haven't found a single instance where it is separated from its preceding verb by more than a personal pronoun. If the object is anything more than that, the "not" follows the verb directly.

You are right that there would be a difference between "I saw him not" and "I saw not him" - the latter would put emphasis (probably contrastive) on "him". But with anything other than a pronoun, the choice does not seem to have been available.

Incidentally, "I think not." is a fossil that survives in modern use, though it sounds rather old-fashioned.

Colin, I believe you are referring to my former update about Jespersen's Cycle, not the latter about Macbeth, right? That's OK, don't worry you misled me. When I ask anybody about anything, be it online or in person, I always rely on my own judgment in the end. Here, I'd just list possible solutions in the updates; I'd just like everybody to know what I am reflecting upon. I do realize some of the solutions may turn out to be invalid. Also, I'll keep trying to formulate my thoughts so that anybody knows they should use their own judgment, too. I appreciate you being cautious!

No, @MIke, your examples from Chaucer match my description: nat follows the pronoun it, but precedes anything else.

In modern or ancient English, what options do you see?
It's anathema?
'He knows it not…'?
'He not knows it…'?
'He it knows not…'?
Do we switch to Yoda-speech…
'It he knows not…'

Robbie, I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. I'm interested in word order in English, just that. If it's a matter of style, fine; of grammar, fine; if it's an exception, also fine.

While not really an answer, its interesting in this case (not universally) that you change the meaning by moving the "not" before or after "it". "He knows it not" is a lack of knowing what it is. "He knows not it" implies he knows something else, but not what "it" is.

Thanks, michaeldthorpe, for the suggested edit, and fev and KillingTime for approving. I am specifically referring to the part "Do you have me?" changed to "Hast thou me?". I consider this an improvement, sounds adequately in this context. But at the same time I need to note it was not me who has come up with it; one shouldn't conclude I know English so well.

I kid you not, this is a great question!

Will you please tell us both what your first language is and further, how far down the ranking English falls?

Can you say how 'he knows it not' should be better expressed?
I myself never saw any problem and then doesn't alter ther the fact that you did.
Can you re-phrase the problem, if only to help me and others like me?

Robbie, first, my first language is Polish, and English is my second language. I guess I know English as good as one knows its second language, on average; I'm afraid I can't say more precisely. Second, in general I have no problem with "he knows it not". It's just that it's interesting as it seems to me, I'd say, different than the word order of other constructs in English.

Przepraszam. Mam około sześciu słów po polsku.
Earlier, I was trying to show that if the question is about the position of the negative, there can be only one. Grammar insists it can't be 'Not he knows it' or 'He not knows it.'
'He knows not it…' might be a special case, and only 'He knows it not…' remains possible.
David S's move to 'He knows not it…' baffles me with 'he knows something else, but not what "it" is.'
I suspect a case can be made for 'He knows not that…' or even 'He knows not that which…' and I also suspect that case would be far off this track.

This is a construction which was already archaic in 1791, and is now obsolete.
In Middle English and Early Modern English, you negated all verbs by following them (sometimes following a pronoun object, which is why it comes after "it") with "not":

I see him not.


They like him not.

We still do this with "be", and (for some speakers, "have"), though not after a pronoun, and we mostly contract the "not" to "n't":

I am not angry!


I haven't any cheese.

and we all do it with auxiliaries (small verbs which precede the main verb and give information about tense, aspect, or modality):

We're not going.


They won't (will not) come.


He can't (cannot) do it.

But around Shakespeare's time it became increasingly common to use the auxiliary "do" with any other verb in the negative (and in questions). Shakespeare used both forms:

See you not? (Macbeth, 2:4:30)


Do you not hope your children shall be kings? (Macbeth 1,3,125)

After Shakespeare's time, the old form gradually disappeared. It survived in formal contexts longer than in ordinary use, but eventually it disappeared, though we are still familiar with it from (eg) the King James Bible.
"Do not", "Did not", and "Does not" of course are often contracted to "don't", "didn't", and "doesn't".

Thanks for the answer! You say that it was the rule to follow the whole predicate with "not", and I think that is close to what I would like to know. Do you know any online materials that describe it, preferably not too scientific?

Actually, I was a bit careless there, @Mike: it usually follows the verb directly, but if the object is short (especially a pronoun like "it" or "him") then that can come before the "not".

Sorry, @Mike, I'm not sure where to direct you. I'm sure there must be introductory resources online, but I haven't found them when I looked.

That's OK, sometimes just to start a discussion is of help. If there is anything available online, I hope to find it!

I've now corrected what I said about "not" following the predicate.

The pattern of adding not after the object is found in contemporary German as well. German "Er weiß es nicht" is word-by-word translation of "He knows it not". So this word order very likely traces back to some variant of Proto-Germanic.

Interestingly, contemporary spoken German in some regions also has uses constructions using the German version "tun" of the English auxiliary "do". But in German these constructions retain the original word order, i.e. you would say "Er tut es nicht wissen", which literally translates to "He does it not know". One could theorize that it were the Romance languages that influenced English here and caused it to go with the simpler word order that keeps the negation right next to the verb.

I don't think it does go back to proto-Germanic, @fgp: in Old English, the negator was a preverbal "ne", which came to be reinforced by a post-verbal "nawiht" ('nothing') which became reduced to "not", and then the "ne" disappeared: a classic example of Jespersen's cycle. I believe the same thing happened independently in German (note that "nicht" ('not') and "nichts" ('nothing') are almost the same word. My personal view is that this postmodifier "not" was unusual for English, and that is one reason why the "do" negative arose.

Also see the I sh*t you not coined phrase.

A somewhat more famous use of the construction from Macbeth: "Is this a dagger which I see before me / The handle toward my hand? Come, let me clutch thee. / I have thee not, and yet I see thee still."  (Act 2, Scene 1)

Also the children's rhyme while pulling petals off a flower: he loves me, he loves me not...

I've made a small update to the question.

I mean, technically the whole "negate a verb by following them with 'not'" is still exactly how English does it.  The difference is that English has also started to almost exclusively negate the verbs "to be", "to have", and "to do", while typically putting most other verbs as an auxiliary to one of those three: e.g. "I [see] him {not}" → "I [do] {not} see him".  The main verb has swapped from "see" to "do", but is still followed (barring a pronoun object in the first case) by "not".

What's the significance of 1791 here?

@iBug it's the publishing date the OP brought up, the example that raised his question.

Archaic by the 1790s? This way of speaking was still in style in the 1990s! "He knows it.... NOT!"

@fgp I don’t think Romance influence would make much sense here, since Romance tends to keep both pronominal objects and negators before the conjugated verb. It seems more likely that English just chose to keep the object with the verb it’s actually the object of; that is, He [knows it] not → He does not [know it]. German, conversely, opted to keep the existing word order, replacing the conjugated verb with an auxiliary and adding on an infinitive at the end. Possibly related to German’s proclivity for clause-final infinitives since North Germanic does it the English way too.

@MaciejStachowski Or slightly less vulgarly (and more originally, I believe), I kid you not.

@RobbieGoodwin Depends on your definition of ‘obsolete’; M-W puts it at 1755, by which standard this wouldn’t be (though not too far off). But when you use expressions like this, you’re deliberately calling up something you know will also be non-standard grammar to the listener, who will recognise it as a reference to an older form you’re both familiar with. It’s not a part of your natural speech to say things like, “I like not spinach” or “I think not this works”.

This formation has been resuscitated in the modern colloquial and sardonic 'He was very good-looking.  Not!', where any statement can be reversed by appending 'Not'.  And it never went away in the chant 'He loves me, he loves me not...'

I do believe in modern English it’s reserved for emphasis or comedic effect, but that demonstrates it can’t be obsolete, nor even approaching obsolescent… as shown by StudioTime and Maciej Stachowski, eg, even if Vicky’s example is a continuation of something archaic.
I suggest only a perverse definition of ‘obsolete’ could include a term likely to be used anew in many if not most British bars, many if not most nights…
Sorry, I also think Laurence's example is similar only homophonically and in fact illustrates a very different case… unless it shows a desire to return to the old form.

Well, I'm happy to call something that is used only as a deliberate archaism "obsolete", but I'm not going to argue the point. I agree that Laurence's example is entirely different syntactically, prosodically, and pragmatically.

Please be sure, if this was about linguistics, it would apply either to several other languages, or to the contrast between English and at least one other language. Does either matter here?
I strongly doubt that form was archaic in 1791, and I'm quite sure it isn't now obsolete… even though today, it's used solely for emphasis.
Would you mind rephrasing the first part of your exposition, ‘… an example of negation where "not" stands neither directly after the auxiliary verb, as it commonly does nowadays ("I do not know"), nor before a verb, as in negation of non-finite clauses (Cambridge Dictionary), nor even directly after the main verb, as it seems to do in the past ("I know not"), but directly after some other word…’?
To me it seems, the idea that that’s an ‘explanation’ is more than confusing enough to be the cause of the problem…
‘… he knows it not…’ is simply archaic; at best, old fashioned. There are cases in modern English where that form is acceptable and I suggest it matters not that they use it solely for emphasis.
Who here doubts 'it matters not…' is a wholly valid phrase?
Fairly clearly ‘… he knows it not…’ always differed from ‘… he does not know it…’ but whether that ever showed anything but emphasis, I do not pretend to understand.
What’s your own view?

But conjectures not supported by any references are not suitable for answers on ELU.

My own view mattersn't.

Robbie, first, I don't know what you mean by "applying to the contrast"; but generally yes, I'm ideally interested in a linguistic view on that word order. It would be great to know any details if its roots really were outside English; but I'll be satisfied if someone could just prove that English has borrowed it from this and this language. Continued.

Continued. Second, what do you mean by "explanation"? Third, how would you rephrase the part you're quoting? Fourth, I think I have expressed my view for the most part in the question. I don't have enough experience with linguistics nor English to judge whether such a word order, or the lack of "do", is archaic, old-fashioned, obsolete, or emphatic.

Really? SE doesn't believe I used the word 'applying…' let alone the phrase 'applying to the contrast…'
Where do your ideas come from, please?

Robbie, I mean, you are saying in the answer, "please be sure, if this was about linguistics, it would apply either to several other languages, or to the contrast between English and at least one other language". I understand the relevant part as "…or [it would apply] to the contrast between English and at least one other language". So here you are talking about the action of applying, and so, for brevity, in my comment I've used just the gerund "applying", omitting the part "the action of".

Good for  you. Another time, please make your edits 'for brevity' both more clear and more helpful. Right now, can you paraphrase your Comment of Dec 5 at 19:57…simply because the difference between the two phrasings is likely to be more helpful than either by itself?
Failing that, can you accept that while 'he knows it not' is archaic, nevertheless that form is today frequently used not only for emphasis or poetic style, but also for its own sake?
If you can take much that on board, we might move on.
Until then, what do you doubt?

Robbie, I'm sorry to hear my comment was not intelligible enough. Probably I might have phrased it another way. But then, I don't see how could I paraphrase the other comment, from 19:57. As I said, I don't have enough experience to judge whether such a phrase is archaic, so I don't want to judge. And I don't see what I should doubt; I think in no comment to your answer I've expressed doubts.

Why, please, is it hard to accept that such a phrase is both archaic, and current?
I do not claim to know what early Anglians meant.
I do insist that modern British listeners are as likely as not to hear exactly that usage in many if not most pubs, on many if not most nights of the week.
Does that really not work for you?
